# How to combine these MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

I have the following `mySQL` [schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/175c6/2/0) and queries on `sqlfiddle`.

Basically I'm trying to fetch a `count` of items within each of the date intervals.

Everything currently works as intended however I have found I have to use several `MySQL` queries in order to retrieve the data required.

Is there some way to combine those queries for an arbitrary number of date intervals? So in the example I have 2 different queries to query 2 different date intervals. I would like to know if it is possible to query, say 3 or 4 or more date intervals in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

You an use `conditional sum` something as

```
select 
sum( 
  case when joined > '2014-01-01' and joined < '2014-06-30'
  then 1 else 0 end
) as count1,
sum( 
  case when joined > '2014-07-01' and joined < '2014-12-31'
  then 1 else 0 end
) as count2
from Users
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on what you mean "combine":

**One Row**

You can use [Abhik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31883148/988423) or something akin to this:

```
SELECT firstHalf.count, secondHalf.count
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(1) as count FROM Users WHERE joined BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-06-30') firstHalf,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) as count FROM Users WHERE joined BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-12-31') secondHalf;
```

**Multiple Rows**

You can use a `UNION ALL` to run the queries at the same time and combine the results:

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT COUNT(1) as count FROM Users WHERE joined BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-06-30') firstHalf
UNION ALL
 (SELECT COUNT(1) as count FROM Users WHERE joined BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-12-31') secondHalf;
```

**The Question You Didn't Ask**

It sounds like you want to get counts for semi-arbitrary date ranges. That's what `GROUP BY` combined with [MySQL Date Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) are for. This will retrieve the counts of all users that joined since the start of 2010, grouped by year and which half of the year (0 or 1) they signed up.

```
SELECT YEAR(joined) as year, MONTH(joined) / 6 AS yearHalf, COUNT(*)
FROM Users
WHERE joined >= '2010-01-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(joined), MONTH(joined) / 6;
```

Using the query format above, you can easily change how finely-grained your counts are, whether they're grouped by year, etc.